# My latest wordpress post is not appearing on in my category of choice

Tags: php, wordpress, post, article

I have published a site on a test url, everything works fine apart from one page I have set to appear a certain category of posts but the most recent post does not appear, if I post another article under that category it pushes the second to last one on the page but still doesn't show the most recent one I posted..Please help..

http://www.scriptposter.com/new/category/gallery/

It pulls it though fine on the homepage tho,

Home
http://www.scriptposter.com/new/

Here is the code I am using :

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
<div class="secondColumn">
<div class="blogFeatureWorkImage">"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumb'); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="thirdColumn2">
<div class="blogFeatureWorkContent">
<h1 class="articleTitle"><span class="yellow">"><?php the_title();?></span></h1>
<p><?php the_content();?></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Is the code you provided taken from the gallery category page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you provided is from the gallery category page, this might be an issue with the way posts are being queried. It should work by default the way you're doing it, but you could try hard-coding a new query on the gallery page [like this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category).

Try putting this directly before the `while` statement to troubleshoot:

```
<?php 
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'gallery', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 
?>
```